# Есть день недели (1-7) и интервал в днях (1-7), как при помощи MOD выбрать нужный день?

Tags: алгоритм, время, arduino, mod, арифметика

Долго гуглил и ломал голову, пожалуйста помогите решить задачку. Проект на Arduino, но мне бы узнать общий алгоритм решения.

Есть 3 переменные:

1. Текущий день недели (currentDayOfWeek, от 1 до 7), получаю в функции loop() от DS3231.
2. Нужный интервал в днях (interval, от 1 до 7), задаю вручную.
3. День недели начала выполнения программы (dayOfWeekStart), получаю от DS3231 один раз в функции setup(), без него думаю никак.

Знаю, что можно сделать иначе (узнавать день месяца, прибавлять к нему интервал, проверять на переполнение и т.п), но меня зацепил вариант именно с днем недели, MOD простейшими и арифметическими действиями.

Моих мозгов хватило только на это:

```
if ( (7 - dayOfWeekStart + currentDayOfWeek) % interval == 0) {
// нужная мне функция
}
```

Набросал пример в Excel:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала алгоритм работает нормально: программу запущена в currentDayOfWeek=1, интервал 3 дня, значит следующее выполнение функции будет в currentDayOfWeek=3, потом 6, затем из-за переполнения (с 7 до 1) функция выполнится на 1 день позже, чем нужно.

Также алгоритм сбивается при старте в другой день, но может есть решение, как его сделать универсальным? Что-нибудь еще прибавлять/вычитать/умножать?

P.S Отбой, наконец-то осознал, что идея дурацкая и решение в одну строку здесь вряд ли возможно. Буду делать стандартно: узнавать текущий день месяца, прибавлять к нему интервал, проверять на переполнение (сброс к началу нового месяца)

Comment: Что значит "текущий" день недели? Сегодня? Тогда и начало работы программы дожно быть задано датой. ===  В *Excel* для наглядости. А нужно где? В оперативке? Уточните задачу.

Comment: Проект на Arduino, текущий день недели получаю от DS3231, день начала выполнения программы (dayOfWeekStart) планирую узнавать один раз в функции setup()

Comment: Все равно непонято... Пример: старт=5,шаг=3. Истина для 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4 ... текущий=1 - где его учитывать для этой линейки? Нужно проверить, является ли ИСТИНА для текущего дня недели? Но в первых неделях 1 (Пн) - ЛОЖЬ и только на третьей неделе ИСТИНА. Т.е. для одного дня недели может быть разная истинность в разных неделях. Как же без даты?

Comment: Верно, для одного дня недели в разные недели может быть разная истинность, для меня главное периодичность в днях. То есть старт=4, шаг=3. Мне нужно, чтобы истина выходила 1 раз в 3 дня, не считая текущий. т.е жду выполнения в 6, 2, 5, 1, 4 и т.д.

Comment: Что-то новое - "не считая текущий". Игнорировать? Или начинать отсчет со следующего дня? Пример: текущий = 4, отсчет начинать с 5?   Похоже, задача простая, но у Вас никак не плучается объяснить...

Comment: Есть линейка 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. Есть заданный день старта S и текущий день Т. Если T<S, то программа не выполняется. Если T>=S, то программа должна определить для текущего дня истинность? Если это так, то непонятка. S=6, T=1 - не считать? Но для S=6 линейка будет 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

Comment: Я не могу просто сравнивать эти числа (T<S), например день старта S=6, интервал выполнения один раз в 3 дня, значит 6, 7 пропускаем, а в 1 жду выполнения. Я изменил текст вопроса, привел другой пример, но под конец уже стал понимать, что наверное вы правы, не получится сделать универсальное решение в одну строчку из тех данных, что есть. Буду делать по другому: узнавать текущий день месяца, прибавлять к нему интервал, проверять на переполнение (сброс к началу нового месяца). Спасибо, что старались помочь!

Comment: В таком случае можно и без даты. Есть возможность считать количество дней, прошедших от старта?

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю

Answer (score 3):

Не получится. Недостаточно информации.
Пример: 
Интервал 5 дней
Поскольку интервал 5 дней, а количество дней в неделе 7(два простых числа), то повторятся график будет один раз в 35 дней. 
При начальной позиции 1 будет как-то так

```
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0
... повтор
```

Имея информацию только о текущем дне недели нельзя определить какая именно неделя сейчас из этих 5ти, потому необходима информация о **количестве дней от старта**, тогда можно запросто сделать деление с остатком и получить нужное число. Фактически, нужна дата. Без нее никак

Comment: Какая именно неделя для меня не важно, мне просто нужно выполнять функцию 1 раз в X дней (от 1 до 7, больше не требуется). Текущий день недели используется только с одной целью: узнать пора выполнять функцию или нет. Например, выбрал интервал 5 дней, на момент запуска программы currentDayOfWeek = 1, значит переменная dayOfWeekStart = 1 (и больше не меняется до перезагрузки устройства), теперь жду выполнения функции в 5, 3, 1 (1 раз в 5 дней)

Comment: @ИвановСергей это невозможно. На второй неделе будет опять currentDayOfWeek ==dayOfWeekStart ==1, хотя неделя другая и график у нее должен быть другой. За временем так или иначе придется следить. При запуске устройства записать текущую дату и от нее уже отталкиваться

Comment: >> *currentDayOfWeek = 1, значит переменная dayOfWeekStart = 1* Но почему? Старт программы начинается с текущего дня? Но Вы же писали, что текущий день не считать...

Answer (score 1):

Если в исходных данных день недели, дату указывать затруднительно, ведь нет понятия, когда программу запустят - на этой неделе, на следующей... Оператор щелкнул тумблер - и работай, чуди... 
Для такого варианта исходных достаточно, но нужен счетчик дней (он использовался как счетчик переполнения).

Например, запускаем программу в Ср (3), начало отсчета - Сб (6). По дате запуска программа видит, что сегодня день 3, смотрит день начала счета и понимает, что рано еще считать... А вот в субботу она проснется и разрешит счет.

Дальше совсем просто: `остаток_от_количества_посчитанных_дней/шаг_(интервал) = 0` - вот он, желаемый день.

---

Исходные: день начала отсчета, интервал.

- Сначала смотрим на счетчик.
- Если счетчик > 0 - переходим к определению *ЛОЖЬ/ИСТИНА*.
- Если пустой, сверяем сегодняшний день недели и день начала счета. Если совпал, переходим к определению *ЛОЖЬ/ИСТИНА*.
- Функцией определяется остаток от деления. После этого програма или выполняет нужные действия в требуемый день, или засыпает до завтра.

---

Для примера- реализация такого алгоритма на *VBA*

```
Const lStep As Long = 5 ' интервал в днях'
Const btDayAccount As Byte = 1 ' день начала отсчета, от 1 до 7'
Dim lCountDay As Long ' счетчик дней с начала отсчета'

Sub test1(i As Long)
Dim btToday As Byte: btToday = DatePart("w", Date + i) ' день текущий'
    If lCountDay = 0 Then ' счетчик еще пустой'
        If btToday = btDayAccount Then Call test2(btToday) ' день совпал - начали счет'
    Else ' счетчик > 0'
        Call test2(btToday) ' продолжаем счет'
    End If
End Sub

Sub test2(btToday As Byte)
    lCountDay = lCountDay + 1 ' счетчик + 1'
    Debug.Print btToday & "_" & fDayX() ' печать в окне Immediate: день и ЛОЖЬ/ИСТИНА'
End Sub

Function fDayX() As Boolean
    fDayX = lCountDay Mod lStep = 0 ' остаток - ИСТИНА/ЛОЖЬ'
End Function

' тестовая проверка - сброс счетчика и запуск программы на 50 дней' 
Sub Main_()
Dim i As Long
    lCountDay = 0
    For i = 1 To 50: Call test1(i): Next i
End Sub
```

Вместо строки с  `Debug.Print` пишем условие

```
 If fDayX() = True Then ' здесь нужные действия'
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо за пример!